# How to cover a subclass of an apex class into test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, callout

I have an apex class and I am writing apex test class for this. All code has been covered except the subclass that is in apex class for which I am writing test class. I have searched a lot but have not gotten my answer. So I am posting this question. I may help others as well.

**My Apex class:**

```
    public class SearchCompanyApex {

        public string searchQuery {get; set;}
        public string myAPIKey {get; set;}

        public List<JSON_Docs> listItems{get;set;}

        public Company_JSON_Result company_json{get; set;}

        public string searchQueryStore {get;set;}

        public string result_httpResponse{get; set;}

        public SearchCompanyApex(){
            Company_connect company_con = new Company_connect();
            myAPIKey = company_con.CompaniesHouseAPIKey;
            searchQuery = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('cname');
            result_httpResponse = '';
            listItems = new List<JSON_Docs>();
            company_json = new Company_JSON_Result();
        }



        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // For Website, making HTTP Request function....
        public string httpReqForCompany(string urlQuery){
            searchQueryStore = urlQuery;
            HttpRequest hReq = new HttpRequest();

            String authStr = myAPIKey+':'+'';
            System.debug('Original String is :' + authStr);

            // create a blob from our parameter value before we send it as part of the url
            Blob authBlob = Blob.valueOf(authStr);
            System.debug('Value of authBlob is : ' + authBlob);

            // base64 encode the blob that contains our url param value
            String authEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(authBlob);

            // print out the encoded value to the debug log so we can see it before/after base64 encode
            System.debug('Encoded value of authBlob is : ' + authEncoded);

            hReq.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+authEncoded);
            hReq.setEndpoint('https://website.api/data='+urlQuery);    
            hReq.setMethod('GET');

            Http h = new Http();
            HttpResponse hResp = h.send(hReq);

            return hResp.getBody();
        }
        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



       // @RemoteAction
        public void SearchCompany(){
            System.debug(searchQuery);
            try{
                result_httpResponse = httpReqForCompany(searchQuery.replace(' ', '&#43;'));  
                company_json = (Company_JSON_Result)JSON.deserialize(result_httpResponse, Company_JSON_Result.class);

///// Code not covered start.......................
                listItems = company_json.items;
///// Code not covered end.......................
                System.debug('hResp.getBody() is : '+result_httpResponse);
                System.debug('listItems is : '+listItems);

            }
            catch(System.Exception e){
             ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Company Search Data Failed: please retry')); 
            }
        }


        //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        // CompaniesHouse Json Data .........................
        public Class Company_JSON_Result{
            public List<JSON_Docs> items;
        }


///// Code not covered start.......................       
        public Class JSON_Docs{
            public string company_number {get;set;}
            public string company_type {get;set;}
            public string title {get;set;}
///// Code not covered end.......................
        }
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    }
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class SearchCompanyApex_TestClass {

     static testMethod void myTest() {
        string apiKey = 'myAPIKeyValue';

        SearchCompanyApex class_test = new SearchCompanyApex();

        // Checking whether Website API key is equal to the saved key...    
        System.assertEquals(class_test.myAPIKey,apiKey);

        // Assigning value = 'Apple' to the variable = 'searchQuery'...
        class_test.searchQuery = 'Apple';

        // It is the main part of this test class. It is call to "getAPIKeyMock" to avoid error : "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts." 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new GetAPIKeyMock(class_test.result_httpResponse));

        // Running search for 'Apple' and comaparing the http Response, page-reference of company responsed..
        class_test.SearchCompany();
        System.assertEquals(class_test.QDetail().getUrl(),'/apex/SearchCompanyFieldsVfp?c=Apple');      
    }



    // This is an inner class to handle WebService callout problems. 
    // Specially to avoid the error : "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts".
    private class GetAPIKeyMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        private string returnedHttpResponse;

        public GetAPIKeyMock(string returnedHttpResponse) {
            this.returnedHttpResponse = returnedHttpResponse;
        }

        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
            // you can use System.assert here and "if" calls to check the request and affect your return if you wish

            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setBody(returnedHttpResponse);

            return res;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Note:** Uncovered parts are shown by using comments.. 
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

Try to insert data into this list `listItems`. You are not using this class except creating the list thats why it is not covering.

One more alternative is create instance of this class and assign value to variable from field and then this class will be covered.

```
SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs ob = new SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs();
ob.company_number ='123';
ob.company_type =' test';
ob.title =' test';



SearchCompanyApex cont= new SearchCompanyApex();
List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs> jsList = new List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs>();
jsList .add(ob);
cont.listItems = jsList ;
```

Comment: How to insert data in the list? Please give me example

Answer (score 2):

Apex inner classes are the same as Java's "Static Nested Classes" and in your code you have

```
public List<JSON_Docs> listItems{get;set;}
```

which is list of JSON_Docs(your class) so you can create a new object of your class in following way

```
SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs objJSON = new SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs();
objJSON.company_number ='Some value';
```

and then you can add that in your test class after controller initialization

```
SearchCompanyApex class_test = new SearchCompanyApex();
List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs> listJSONDocs = new List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs>();
listJSONDocs.add(objJSON);
class_test.listItems = listJSONDocs;
```

so at the end your test class code will be like this

```
SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs objJSON = new SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs();
objJSON.company_number ='Some value';
objJSON.company_type = 'Some value';
objJSON.title = 'Some value';
SearchCompanyApex class_test = new SearchCompanyApex();
List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs> listJSONDocs = new     
List<SearchCompanyApex.JSON_Docs>();
listJSONDocs.add(objJSON);
class_test.listItems = listJSONDocs;
```

Comment: The whole code you just posted has to add in test class?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: Now only use system. assert() to check the results???

Comment: yes you can do that. by putting system.assertequals(1, class_test.listItems.size());

Comment: It covers the class declaration but is not covering the uncovered code in upper class.

Comment: which part of upper class

Comment: ///// Code not covered start.......................
                listItems = company_json.items;
///// Code not covered end.......................

Comment: it seems like your httpReqForCompany method is throwing exception and not returning any data you need to check debug log for exception.  make sure your mock class is returning data which you are using  in your test class.